# How can I monitor all activity from only one software with Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, capture, traffic-filtering

I would like to know if it is possible in WireShark to monitor ONLY the activity coming from a single software.

p.e. if I use CSVpad.exe, how can I monitor all activity from CSVpad?

Comment: If you have that information available within Wireshark you can probably define a filter. If you don't you could create a (virtual) network interface and let only one application use it (highly configuration dependent). If that isn't an option either you don't.

Answer (score 5):

Find out what port number the application in question is using and apply a port filter to the capture. Two applications cannot use the same port, so it will be unique.

To find which port your application is using, launch a command prompt as Administrator and run `netstat -a -b`.

You can add a filter under Capture > Capture Filters...

[image: Capture Filters]

Then go to Capture > Options and apply the filter to your interface

[image: Interfaces]

If you need to capture multiple ports, you can do so like this:

[image: Multiple Ports]

Comment: Thank you Layne, but where do you find the port number of an application? Don't applications use multiple ports (depending on the protocol)?

Comment: According to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows , you can use `netstat -a -b` in CMD to find what port an application is using. Some applications do use multiple ports; I have updated my answer to show how you can filter for multiple ports.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware this still isn't possible to do with Wireshark.  There is a long-standing enhancement bug request for this feature to be added though in case you want to track it.  It's [Wireshark Bug 1184](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1184).

I believe [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226), the successor to [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865), supports this though, although I've never experimented with it myself.